# Android: What sdk do I need to install

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

If I make an app targeting sdk2.2(api8) to sdk4.4.2, do I need to install every sdk from 2.2-4.4.2? Also should I install all the Android Build Tools?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you only need to install the newest SDK and the newest Build tools

Comment: Probably not appropiate question for SO, just install the Android SDK and follow the help pages. If you don't have time to learn it, pay someone to build what you want for you.

Comment: No, that's not true.  If you want to target different operating system levels then with the Android SDK Manager you should download the targets that you wish to be dealing with.  At some point it is worth downloading them all so that you have everything you need available.  Such a task that is good right before finishing for the day and let it all download overnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in the specific case you mentioned: MinSdk 2.2 to TargetSdk 4.4.2.

You only need to download the SDK for Android 4.4.2, not 2.2. Nor do you need the SDKs in between.

But yes, you do need to download the latest Android Build Tools and keep those up-to-date.